# New permalink structure: nginx rewrite loop

Tags: linux, nginx, rewrite, permalinks

I build a new permalink structure on my website. After adding some nginx rewrite rules, there is a redirect loop to /vlogger/info/info/info/info/...

Old permalink:

```
/vlogger/user-name
```

New permalink:

```
/vlogger/info/user-name
```

current nginx rule:

```
location ~ /vlogger/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/vlogger/info/$1 permanent;
}
```

How can I check if the second directory ( /vlogger/"info/" ) alway set and redirect successful without a loop?

(*Username contains only: a-z0-9 and - (minus))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
rewrite ^/vlogger/([^/]*)$ /vlogger/info/$1 permanent;
```

This redirect from /vlogger/name to /vlogger/info/name

Answer (score 1):

Nginx terminates the search of regular expressions *on the first match*. Thus, just put a more specific match above it. You need to use a regular expression match again (imo) because prefix matches are only used when no regular expression matches. (I highly recommend to read the manual: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

```
location ~ /vlogger/info/(.*)$ {
    # whatever you want to do with them
}

location ~ /vlogger/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ /vlogger/info/$1 permanent;
}
```

Please note that regex is probably not necessary in your case (if you have other regex you might need to use regex tho, imo. Again, read the manual entry). You might get better performance with prefix strings...

```
location /vlogger/info/ {
    # whatever you want to do with them
}

location /vlogger/ {
    rewrite ^ /vlogger/info/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Your answer missed the space between `rewrite` source and destination, I fixed your answer.